# How can I split this date?

Tags: r, csv, tidyr, lubridate

I am working with this dataset and I am trying to separate the 'Date' column into the day, month, and year but have run into a problem doing it because it has the month as a character value. Any help would be great.
Here's an image: [Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjtpO.png)

Comment: Does `19May19` mean May 19, 2019?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your `Date` column using `as.Date()`, specifying the format for the date; in this case, one option is `"%d%B%y"`

```
library(lubridate)
dataset = data.frame(Date=c("19MAY19","31MAY19"))
dataset %>% mutate(Date = as.Date(Date,"%d%B%y"),
                   y = year(Date),m=month(Date),d = day(Date))
```

Output:

```
        Date    y m  d
1 2019-05-19 2019 5 19
2 2019-05-31 2019 5 31
```